# Gatling-scala check 2 status codes (either or)

Tags: scala, rest, gatling

In a gatling test, I am trying to verify whether the response for a request is either 204 or 404.

```
val scn = scenario("Scenario A").exec(httpRequest
    .check(status.is(204)))
```

where httpRequest is a request defined elsewhere. I want to check whether the test to pass is response is 204 or 404. Couldnt find anything to use or in a    check

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.6/http/http_check.html#validating):

```
status.in(204, 404)
```